# is there a GetElementByTagName that handles if the tag isn't there

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

i have the following code below but sometime the "serving_description" tag isn't there.  Right now i just put a try catch around it but i wanted to find out if there was a cleaner way to handle this scenario.

```
XmlElement servingElement = (XmlElement)servingNode;
serving.Id = Convert.ToInt32(servingElement.GetElementsByTagName("serving_id")[0].InnerText);
serving.Name = servingElement.GetElementsByTagName("serving_description")[0].InnerText;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rather check that the returning *NodeList* is *not null* and check that the *count is greater than zero* before using defaulting to a *try catch*.

Something simple like

```
serving.Name = "defaultName";
XmlNodeList elemList = servingElement.GetElementsByTagName("serving_description");
if (elemList != null && elemList.Count > 0)
    serving.Name = elemList[0].InnerText;
```

**EDIT**

If I am not mistaken, you might not even have to check for the *null* as the *GetElementsByTagName* method might just return an empty list(*but I cannot verify that right now, sorry*)

Comment: @astander - from memory, I think you're right - you get an empty (but non-null) node-set.